Broke down my nvidia-smi when I tried updating nvidia drivers
Problem
I have seen many similar questions in this forum, and I have tried many of the solutions proposed, however nothing seems to work :c
I was trying to install CUDA from the CUDA installation guide. This process asks to install the CUDA toolkit and during this process I had to update the nvidia drivers.
I tried updating my nvidia drivers from the website for my configuration. I have an NVIDIA RTX4000 ADA, and I'm using a lunix computer with Ubuntu 22.04. On the website it says that the latest driver is the nvidia driver-550. I dowloaded the file and tried running the installation from terminal by running:
./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-550.67.run. However there was a warning prompt saying that I should do the update from the ubuntu application "Software & updates". So I cancelled the updates and I went to this app and selected the drivers that said recommended. I reboot my pc and now whenever I try running nvidia-smi  I get the following error:

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

I tried reinstalling the drivers and I broke the setup even further or something because now when I open "Software & updates" I don't even get a recommended option...
I'm sorry I am not very tech savvy, should I restore my computer from factory settings or can this problem be fixed?
Debug output

sudo lshw -C display

*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
   configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=1920x1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:640-63f memory:96000000-96ffffff memory:6000000000-63ffffffff memory:6400000000-6401ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:97080000-970fffff


sudo dkms status
nvidia/550.54.14, 6.1.0-1036-oem, x86_64: installed


What I have tried (Update)
Tried reinstalling the drivers in many ways and even from a root shell ( Nvidia Driver Broken on Update - Unable to Reinstall ) . Tried sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall and sudo reboot.
I feel like I am trying random stuff at this point because I don't really know what is broken in the first place...

I have fixed my issue. I retried this sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall and follow the instructions on the screen. At some point, it asks you to create a password to ensure it is you (the user) making the installation.
The problem was actually coming from the MOK menu / secure boot that appears when you restart the computer. Instead of pressing continue, you have to go to the enroll MOK option. I created my password with an azerty keyboard but when I was trying to put the password on this menu, the keyboard acts as a qwerty keyboard...
So keep this in mind when running the updates!

Had the same issue today with the 550.67 driver -- but on Pop OS 22.04.
I had CUDA running beforehand, but wanted to update for getting TensorFlow
to work. My card is a GTX 1050 ... I can run after cleanup 470 version.
There no CUDA is provided. Others I did not try till now.
You can check your driver history like that to find out, which driver you had before:
#!/bin/bash
log_path="/var/log"
grep -h "nvidia-driver" $log_path/dpkg.log* | grep "install " | sort -u

